# Cleaning up print command

Tags: python

I am using this line of code:

```py
fwhost1 = "172.16.17.1"
print("Connecting via API call, backing up the configuration for:", fwhost1)
```

The output from this line is:

```py
('Connecting via API call, backing up the configuration for:', '172.16.17.1')
```

I am looking to not have the parenthesis and the single quotes appear on the output while the script is running.

Thank you

I have tried adjusting the line of code but this is the only way it will run without an error

Comment: do you know how to use `format` for strings?

Comment: Strange. Mine doesn't print it like that. What editor are you using?

Comment: @Reedinationer python 2 will print the parenthesis.

Comment: Better upgrade to Python 3 if you can ...

Comment: @MarkMeyer Ah good call. I assumed because parenthesis were present it was python 3.X. OP you should really consider upgrading since 2.X will be discontinued soon!

Comment: Plus you get the sweet `f` string formatting in Python3.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `+` operator to concatenate strings. More info [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/concatenation/string-concatenation-and-formatting-in-python)

```
fwhost1 = "172.16.17.1" 
print("Connecting via API call, backing up the configuration for: " + fwhost1)
```

Here's another way of printing using %-formatting

```
print("Connecting via API call, backing up the configuration for: %s" % fwhost1)
```

Another option is using `str.format()`

```
print("Connecting via API call, backing up the configuration for: {}".format(fwhost1))
```

If you're using Python 3, you can use [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

```
print(f"Connecting via API call, backing up the configuration for: {fwhost1}")
```

Output

> Connecting via API call, backing up the configuration for: 172.16.17.1

Comment: Thank you for this answer nathancy I learned something along the way and it worked - much appreciated. Now to figure out why the % worked :-)

Comment: Glad to help, check [this](https://pyformat.info/) out for more information on % formatting

Answer (score 2):

A more pythonic way is to use `format` function over strings

```
fwhost1 = "172.16.17.1"
print ("Connecting via API call, backing up the configuration for:{}".format(fwhost1))
```